# Bootstrap3 global styling is not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have loaded bootsrtap3 with jquery 1.9 but the global styling is not working for text fields.

My text fileds are not styled. Should I add any classes to them?

**Note**

I don't want to style them with `form-control` class because of the problem with its 100% width. I just want that my text fields get styled like in bootstrap2.

Comment: Please add some example code to your question. Try to add `.form-control {width:auto;}` to overrule the 100% width;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would recommend doing:

`<input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:150px;" />`

change `150px` to a width of your choice.